# How to properly initialise a struct in which one of the members is an array?

Tags: c

I defined the following struct:

```
typedef struct sp_point_t* SPPoint;

struct sp_point_t
{
    int dim;
    int index;
    double* data;
};
```

And then I wanted to initialise an instance of the struct:

```
foo (double* data, int dim, int index)
{
double* dataInserted;
dataInserted = (double*) calloc(dim,sizeof(double));
//inserting values to dataInserted 
SPPoint newPoint = {dim, index, dataInserted}; // warning!
}
```

But at compilation time I got an "excess elements in scalar initializer" warring (on the last line).

What does this warning mean? why can't I initialise an instance this way?

Thanks

Comment: You do not need the cast on `calloc` - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon, and also the information about creating an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You've not shown the typedef for `SPPoint`.  Is it `typedef struct sp_point_t SPPoint;` or `typedef struct sp_point_t *SPPoint;` or something else altogether?  You've also not shown the local variables `dim` or `index` either.  These omissions make it impossible to determine what needs to be done to fix your problem.  My guess is that you've got a pointer (in which case, read [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/)).

Comment: `data` is a pointer, not an array

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing a pointer to struct instead of the stuct itself. The following works (if you meant struct creation in your code):

```
foo (double* data, int dim, int index)
{
    double* dataInserted;
    dataInserted = (double*) calloc(dim,sizeof(double));
    //inserting values to dataInserted
    struct sp_point_t newPoint  = {dim, index, dataInserted}; // Corrected code
}
```